# Error in Qt Creator with "undefined reference to qt_static_plugin_ (plugin here)"

Tags: linux, qt, qt-creator

I have been having this issue for a bit now and I cannot seem to fix it. I use to not get this error and one day it just started to appear even on projects that already built successfully.

I am building projects on Qt Creator on version 5.11.3 of Qt that I used for cross compiling onto a Raspi 3. Although when I build I am now getting the same error for my projects which did not happen appear earlier and I cannot figure out why. I Attached pictures of the issues.

[image: Image of Errors Occurring]

[image: Image of File Where Errors Occur]

If Anyone has any ideas or has seen this before and got it to be debugged.

Comment: You need to install that plugin , what is your os? And you should include it's path in .pro

Comment: My OS is Ubuntu, and the path is home/desktop/App Launcher/Source/appLauncher.pro

Comment: And would I need to install every single plugin I got an error for?

Comment: You need to install QGifplugin , in your system.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link or anything of the sorts for how to install it I am sorry I am just very new to Qt and also because I assume I would have to install all 40 plugins that I am getting errors for since it is not just the QGifplugin but many other plugins as can be seen from the second picture that I am getting errors for.